# Simulate a button click event via a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```
<button type="button" 
    data-toggle="modal" id="testing" 
    class="btn btn-icon btn-primary glyphicons circle_ok" 
    data-target="#myModal"><i></i>
</button>
```

I'd like simulate a click via a function executed when the page is loaded.

How can I do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried .trigger('click')?

Comment: or `$('button#testing').click();`

Comment: hope simulate doesn't mean the visual change takes place while clicking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the shorthand method [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click)

```
$('your-button-selector').click()
```

or [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters)

```
$('your-button-selector').trigger('click')
```

To simulate a click event, it will run all registered click event handlers, but may/may not trigger the default action

Answer (score 1):

[`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

You can use `.trigger('click');`

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code to your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

  $('button#testing').click()

});

</script>
```

[Here is a working demo](http://jsbin.com/azosiw/1/)