# How to simulate click on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My objective is **not simple redirection**!

Even before you mark it as duplicate, I've already tried [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript), [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954623/simulate-a-button-click-event-via-a-function). It didn't worked. I've tried it in following code.

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="test_class">click me</a>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //$('.test_class').click();
        $('.test_class').trigger('click');
    },10);

});
</script>
```

I've tried the click event with and without `setTimeout`, nothing worked. I've tried with id as well, it didn't worked. I'm using **google chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit) on ubuntu 14.04**, if at all it matters.

**Edit:**
I've tried following variations as well just now, and they didn't worked :(

```
 $(document).ready(function() { //removed quotes.
    setTimeout(function() {
        //$('.test_class').click();
        $('.test_class').trigger('click');
    },10);

});
```

This one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //$('.test_class').click();
        $('.test_class')[0].trigger('click'); //added array representation
    },10);

});
```

And This one, Peculiarity of this click event is that I can see alert, but the click event of `<a>` isn't happening.

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="test_class">click me</a>
<div class="submit_btn" style="display:none;" onclick="dothis();"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function dothis()
{
    alert('dskjhfjkds');
    $('.test_class').click();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //$('.test_class').click();
        $('.submit_btn').click();
    },10);

});

//$('.test_class')[0].trigger('click');
</script>
```

p.s. My actual scenario of of click event differs, it is not simple redirection to google website.

Comment: `$(document).ready();` (without quotes)

Comment: Does it still not work when the link simply points to a URL?

Comment: `$('.test_class')[0].click()`

Comment: @D4V1D didn't worked :|

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically click a link with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I've already tried the id method, I've shared the link myself in my question! So, it doesn't look like a duplicate to me :)

Comment: Why must the AJAX call to your server be triggered by a click?

Comment: Why is it marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
$('.test_class')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `href` attribute is not followed when you trigger the click event on a `<a>` element.

Therefore:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="test_class">click me</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.test_class').click(); // this won't trigger the link to google.com
        },10);
    });
</script>
```

Won't have any effect when:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onClick="alert('this is an alert');" class="test_class">click me</a> <!-- notice the onClick attribute -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.test_class').click(); // this will trigger the alert
        },10);
    });
</script>
```

This one will.

I guess there must be something preventing links with `href` attribute to be triggered by Javascript.

If you want to perform a redirect in HTML, I suggest you to dig into the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.mydomain.tld">` tag.

Comment: As I said, I don't need simple redirection in my question earlier. Basically I need to click a element on page load and it will trigger ajax call to my server.

Comment: Anyways, I don't see the alert as well. I copied your code and saved it as abc.html, but I don't see the alert. I'm on chrome.

Comment: @Abhishek: Why don't you simply do your ajax call on `$(document).ready();`? You should see the alert, here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jhc8L4s/).

Comment: That ajax call happens on click of one element on the page, that is the reason I'm trying to click that element.

Comment: @Abhishek: Can you share the binding event of that one element to the Ajax call please?

Comment: It is in rails. `<%= link_to "Test Click", my_path(:action_id =>'test_click'), remote: true, :class => "js_elem" %>`. The `remote: true` will do ajax call for me. I don't have to handle anything in this case.. hence I don't have any ajax call binded to that element

Comment: Sorry, I have no use of Rails. Cannot help you on this one.

Comment: That's okay.. Thanks for your time. Anyways, if this click thing can be resolved then I can resolve my rails issue as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the DOM event click for the element by accessing `$('.test_class')[0]`:

```
$('.test_class')[0].click();
```